# Restoring a database back to a point in time before full backup was made

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, restore, transaction-log

A problem with one of our database tables arose at the end of last week and I wanted to restore that database to a server in order to retrieve the table. We only have the last backup, and a full set of transaction logs before the error occurred, up to and after the full back was taken.

However, when I restore, I can only use the transaction logs to roll forward, not back. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

**Sequence of events:**

- Error occurred: Friday April 5 at 12:00
- Full backup taken: Sunday April 7 at 02:00

Many thanks.

Comment: No, that is not possible. What was the nature of the error that occurred?

Comment: Depending on what the nature of the error was and how valuable the lost data is, there may be a recovery route via specialist help or 3rd party tools. Was it a delete/drop or something more complicated?

Comment: It was a bad update which caused a large dataset to be updated with the wrong information. Not terribly valuable, no, but an annoyance to repopulate. :)

Comment: I restored the db from an archived backup and rolled forward, so no spilt milk. Thanks all for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Its very difficult to reverse engineer and interpret SQL T-log records. As mentioned there are 3rd party tools like [APEX SQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) , [RedGate's LOG Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/), [Log Explorer](http://www.logon-int.com/product.asp?sProdClassCode=LUM-P-0001)

Also, there is an undocumented command **fn_dblog** that can be used as below, but you wont have the flexibility like 3rd party tools.

```
SELECT 
    [Previous LSN],
    [Current LSN],
    [Operation],
    [AllocUnitName],
    [Page ID],[SPID],
    [Begin Time], 
    [Transaction Name],
    [Lock Information] 

FROM ::fn_dblog(null, null)
GO
```

Paul Randal has described how to read from T-log with excellent examples -- [Using fn_dblog, fn_dump_dblog, and restoring with STOPBEFOREMARK to an LSN](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Redgate and Log Explorer software are only for SQL Server 2000 however.